# Error when tring to get lots of data

Tags: sql-server-2005

When I run the report for a few days then its good. but if I try to retrive data for more then a year then I get this error message.

I tried to run DBCC CHECKDB as it says in the error, but after 10 min running a error came up that it can't continue.

```
SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:952663; actual 2668:-1594740640).
It occurred during a read of page (1:952663) in database ID 5 at offset 0x000001d12ae000 in file 'F:\Data\PointOfSale.mdf'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Comment: What do the Windows error logs tell you?

Comment: Perhaps a restore of this database to another server and then running DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_REBUILD / 
REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS to assess the impact.

Comment: When I backup and restore the problem would not go with the bak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is due to data corruption on page 952663 on F:\Data\PointOfSale.mdf.

The error is not due to large data being returned. One of the pages in your result set is corrupt. You can still circumvent the corrupt pages and get back a large result set.

You can do what @jl01 suggests or you can also try a [page level restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191253%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for page 952663.

Comment: RESTORE PAGE is not allowed with databases that use the simple recovery model.